# Find the sum of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the sum of this series, where k is from 1 to infinity?

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^3+6k^2+11k+5}{(k+3)!}$$

Comment: It converges, use the sum to infinity formula!

Comment: $$k^3+6k^2+11k+5 = (k+3)(k+2)(k+1) - 1$$

Comment: @Nick: It converges. There is a factorial at the denominator.

Comment: @ClementC.: Slip of tongue :D

Answer (score 4):

That series can be written:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac 1{k!}-\frac 1{(k+3)!}\right)$$
so it is $(e-1)-(e-1-1/1-1/2-1/6)=5/3$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As the numerator is **cubic**, we need to express  $\displaystyle k^3+6k^2+11k+5$

as $1\cdot(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)+b_1(k+3)(k+2)+b_2(k+3)+b_3$ where $b_i$s are arbitrary   constants

Observe  that we have to start with $k+3$ as it is there in the factorial of the denominator.

Had the numerator been **square** polynomial like $A k^2+Bk+C$ with the denominator $(k+r)!$

we had to start with $A\cdot (k+r)(k+r-1)+a_1(k+r)+a_2$

---

Here we have
$$\frac{k^3+6k^2+11k+5}{(k+3)!}=\frac{(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)+b_1(k+3)(k+2)+b_2(k+3)+b_3}{(k+3)!}$$

$$=\frac1{(k)!}+b_1\frac1{(k+1)!}+b_2\frac1{(k+2)!}+b_3\frac1{(k+3)!}$$

Multiplying either sides by $(k+3)!$ we get $$k^3+6k^2+11k+5=(k+3)(k+2)(k+1)+b_1(k+3)(k+2)+b_2(k+3)+b_3$$

Methods to determine $b_i$s:

**Method** $\#1:$

Set $k+3=0$ to find $b_3$

$k+2=0$ to find $b_2$ in terms of $b_3$ which is known

and so on

**Method** $\#2:$

Compare the coefficients of the different powers of $k$